# How to make a MySQL query that checks if the column is the beginning of another string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Folders that has a column called path.
I want to get all folders whose path that could be the beginning for "folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/".

Acceptable folders would be ones with paths like "folder1/", "folder1/folder2/" or even "folder1/fold", I'm not really worried about this last example. An unacceptable answer would be "folder2/".

Is there a way to make such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
where 'folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/' like concat(path, '%')
```